# Maximize the minimum absolute value of the differences of three permutation sequences

Tags: permutations, maxima-minima

I have been plagued by this problem for a long time:
there are three permutation sequences with the same length N, denoted as x1, x2, and x3. For example, if N=5, x1, x2, x3 can be [1 2 3 4 5], [5 3 1 2 4] and [3 2 1 4 5].

We calculate the absolute values of differences between any two sequences, that is min{|x1-x2|}=1, min{|x1-x3|}=0, min{|x2-x3|}=0. Therefore, the minimum absolute value of the differences of the three permutation sequences is 0. However, when we change the orders of numbers in x1, x2 and x3 as [1 2 3 4 5], [3 4 5 1 2] and [5 1 2 3 4], the minimum absolute value of the differences of three permutation sequences will be 1.

Now, We want to find some x1, x2, and x3, to make the minimum absolute value of the differences maximize. It is so difficult to make an exhaustive search. Does anyone have any ideas about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that [1,2,3, ... , N] with two cyclic permutations would always retrieve the maximal minimum absolute value (MAV) of $\left \lfloor{\frac{N}{3}}\right \rfloor$ (the result of rounding N/3 down). I'll give a short sketch for how I would prove this.

---

**First, we want to prove that there is no set of three permutations which would result in a MAV greater than $\bf k = \left \lfloor{\frac{N}{3}}\right \rfloor$.** Without loss of generality, assume the first permuation is $[1,2,3, ... , N]$. Let $[x_1,x_2,x_3, ... , x_N]$ and $[y_1,y_2,y_3, ... , y_N]$ be the two other permutations. Consider the MAV for just the $k$ and $k+1$ elements of this set of three permutations.

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ \vdots \\ k \\ k+1 \\ \vdots \\ N \end{bmatrix} \quad \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ \vdots \\ x_k \\ x_{k+1} \\ \vdots \\ x_N \end{bmatrix} \quad \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \\ \vdots \\ y_k \\ y_{k+1} \\ \vdots \\ y_N \end{bmatrix}
$$

This is two "rows" of the permutations. The MAV for this set of three permutations must be less than or equal to the MAV of just these two rows. However, $x_k, x_{k+1}, y_k, y_{k+1} \in \{1,2,3, ..., N\}$ so (and there is some hand-waving here) the MAV of these two rows is $k$, corresponding to $[k,2k,3k]$ (for $N=3k$ or $N=3k+1$) or $[k+1,2k+1,3k+2]$ (for $N=3k+2$).

Because the MAV of these two rows is $k$, the MAV of this set of three permutations must be less than or equal to $k$. The choice of $[1,2,3, ... , N]$ for the first permutation was arbitrary (we can apply any permutation to each of the three permutations) so this is a general result. Thus, the maximal MAV must be less than or equal to $k$.

---

**Second, we need to prove that the maximal MAV is greater than or equal to $k$.** We can simply give one example of a set of three permutations that has an MAV equal to $k$. I will only give an example for $N=3k+2$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\ k \\ k+1 \\ \vdots \\ 2k \\ 2k+1 \\ \vdots \\ 3k \\ 3k+1 \\ 3k+2 \end{bmatrix} \quad \begin{bmatrix} 2k+3 \\ \vdots \\ 3k+2 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ k \\ k+1 \\ \vdots \\ 2k \\ 2k+1 \\ 2k+2 \end{bmatrix} \quad \begin{bmatrix} k+3 \\ \vdots \\ 2k+2 \\ 2k+3 \\ \vdots \\ 3k+2 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ k \\ k+1 \\ k+2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

In each row, pairs have a difference of either $k$ or $k+2$. Thus, each row has a MAV of at least $k$. The last row will always have an MAV of $k$ and so the MAV of this set of three permutations is $k$.

---

By showing that the maximal MAV $\leq k$ and also that the maximal MAV $\geq k$, we prove that the maximal MAV $= k$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It is of great help to me. As you said, the maximal MAV = k. But the proof seems to be given by giving examples, and I wonder whether it can be proved in theory. Moreover, the permutation sequences are not cyclic here, for example, [1 3 5 2 4], [3 1 4 2 5], and [5 3 2 4 1]. What do you think about the solution to this situation?

Comment: @opennature In the first part of the proof, the numbers $x_i,y_i$ can be in any order (not just a cyclic permutation), so this applies to all sets of three permutations. For the second part of the proof, I gave an example for a solution with maximal MAV $= k$ that uses cyclic permutations; for your N=5 case, this would spit out [1,2,3,4,5], [5,1,2,3,4], and [4,5,1,2,3] for a maximal MAV of 1.If you want all possible solutions then that would be much more difficult! ... Probably too advanced for me without a computer algorithm, haha

Comment: Ok, I want to obtain the maximal MAV in theory, and don't need to find all the possible solutions. But there are two questions about the first part of the proof. First, there are two notation "k". One is $\bf k = \left \lfloor{\frac{N}{3}}\right \rfloor$ and the other is "the k and k+1 elements of this set of three permutations." Are the two notations the same? The second question may overlap with the first one. Are the k and k+1elements arbitrary elements in the sequences？Why do you choose this way？

Comment: @opennature Yes, the two notations are the same (they look a bit different because I am not so good at formatting unfortunately...); so the $k$ and $k+1$ elements of the three permutations are specific rows, not arbitrary rows. These rows look like $[k, x_k, y_k]$ and $[k+1,x_{k+1},y_{k+1}]$. Of these two rows, at least one will have a MAV $=k$. Thus, the three permutations must have a MAV of at most $k$!

Comment: You proved that MAV must be greater than k, but does not get the exact maximum MAV. How to solve this problem? From your answer, I think that this problem may be simplified to three integers ${x_1},{x_2},{x_3} \in \left\{ {1,2,3,...,N} \right\}$ to find the maximum difference between them.

Comment: @opennature Just to be clear, the first part proves that the maximal MAV $\leq k$ by looking at the $k$ and $k+1$ elements. The second part proves that the maximal MAV $\geq k$ by giving an example of three permutations with a MAV $=k$. These two points imply that the maximal MAV $=k$. And yes, the problem mostly simplifies to looking at sets of three integers from $\{1,2,3, ... , N\}$.

Comment: I see. That's great. Thank you again for your reply